# Draw two symmetrical pseudo root nodes for binary tree using tikz

Tags: tikz-trees, alignment

I need to draw a binary tree (in fact the Stern-Brocot tree) with two pseudo nodes as parents to the root, as seen in the first picture.
[image: this is how the result should look]

At the moment I'm using tikz to draw it but the two pseudo nodes are all the way on the left. (See second picture) How can I align them or is there another completely different, better aproach?
[image: this is what I currently have]

The code I'm using:

```tex
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikzset{
                level 1/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=65mm},
                level 2/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=30mm},
                level 3/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=15mm},
                level 4/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=10mm},
            }
            \node {$\frac{1}{1}$}
            child[grow=up, left] {node {$\frac{0}{1}$} edge from parent[dashed]} 
            child[grow=up, right] {node {$\frac{1}{0}$} edge from parent[dashed]} 
            child {node {$\frac{1}{2}$}
                child {node {$\frac{1}{3}$}
                    child {node {$\frac{1}{4}$}}
                    child {node {$\frac{2}{5}$}}
                }
                child {node {$\frac{2}{3}$}
                    child {node {$\frac{3}{5}$}}
                    child {node {$\frac{3}{4}$}}
                }
            }
            child {node {$\frac{2}{1}$}
                child {node {$\frac{3}{2}$}
                    child {node {$\frac{4}{3}$}}
                    child {node {$\frac{5}{3}$}}
                }
                child {node {$\frac{3}{1}$}
                    child {node {$\frac{5}{2}$}}
                    child {node {$\frac{4}{1}$}}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Since the question is closed, and the duplicate does not give a suitable answer (in my opinion), I'll give my two cents here. Just name your root node by `\node (ROOT) {$\frac{1}{1}$}`, and add after your tree code a simple `tikz` drawing code, like : `\def\L{5cm} \def\H{1cm}
            \draw[dashed] (ROOT) --++ (\L,\H) node[right] {$\frac{0}{1}$};
            \draw[dashed] (ROOT) --++ (-\L,\H) node[left] {$\frac{1}{0}$};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what I am doing, but I played around...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikzset{
                level 1/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=65mm},
                level 2/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=30mm},
                level 3/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=15mm},
                level 4/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=10mm},
            }
            \node {$\frac{1}{1}$}
            child[grow=up, left=7cm] {node {$\frac{0}{1}$} edge from parent[dashed]} 
            child[grow=up, right=7cm] {node {$\frac{1}{0}$} edge from parent[dashed]} 
            child [left=6cm] {node {$\frac{1}{2}$}
                child [right=-.5cm] {node {$\frac{1}{3}$}
                    child {node {$\frac{1}{4}$}}
                    child {node {$\frac{2}{5}$}}
                }
                child [left=-.5cm] {node {$\frac{2}{3}$}
                    child {node {$\frac{3}{5}$}}
                    child {node {$\frac{3}{4}$}}
                }
            }
            child [left=6cm]  {node {$\frac{2}{1}$}
                child [right=-.5cm] {node {$\frac{3}{2}$}
                    child {node {$\frac{4}{3}$}}
                    child {node {$\frac{5}{3}$}}
                }
                child [left=-.5cm] {node {$\frac{3}{1}$}
                    child {node {$\frac{5}{2}$}}
                    child {node {$\frac{4}{1}$}}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot!
Did you find those values by trial and error or is there a "good" way to do this?

Comment: @sev There may be a better way, but I did trial and error.  Note, even with that, there is a symmetry to the trial/error values, which simplifies things.